# I can't type anything on certain scanner

Tags: java

I've been creating a simple library system for the past few days, I have completed the population per shelf, displays, etc. thanks to this site. currently, I'm having trouble with a borrower borrowing either a physical book, or download an e-book or borrow an equipment. firstly, there was a null point exception error when running, an error when calling the borrowBookPH, and lastly, I don't know if the book is really being borrowed or downloaded.

I've posted a shortened code of my Library Project.

Edit: I've managed to figure out what's causing my problem. and surfaced a new one, Right now my problem is that I can't type any string when asked "Input Book/Equipment Name:" There are no errors / warnings on my code.

Driver Class:

```
System.out.println("Input Borrower: ");
    int borrowerID = sc.nextInt();

    switch(borrowerID){

    case 11074450: System.out.println("1. Physical 2. Digital 3. Equipment: ");
                    int choice = sc.nextInt();
                    switch(choice){
                        case 1: System.out.println("Input Book Name: ");
                                String borrowIP = sc.nextLine();
                                for(int i = 0; i < ph.size(); i++){
                                    if(borrowIP.equals(ph.get(i).getTitle()))
                                        brw1.borrowBookPH(ph.get(i));
                                }
                                break;
                        case 2: System.out.println("Input Book Name: ");
                                String borrowID = sc.nextLine();
                                for(int i = 0; i < dg.size(); i++){
                                    if(borrowID.equals(dg.get(i).getTitle()))
                                        brw1.downloadBookDG(dg.get(i));
                                }
                                break;
                        case 3: System.out.println("Input Equipment Name: ");
                                String borrowIE = sc.nextLine();
                                for(int i = 0; i < eqp.size(); i++){
                                    if(borrowIE.equals(eqp.get(i).getName()))
                                        brw1.borrowEQ(eqp.get(i));
                                }
                                break;
                    }
                    break;
    case 10355230: System.out.println("1. Physical 2. Digital 3. Equipment: ");
                    int choice2 = sc.nextInt();
                    switch(choice2){
                        case 1: System.out.println("Input Book Name: ");
                                String borrowIP = sc.nextLine();
                                for(int i = 0; i < ph.size(); i++){
                                    if(borrowIP.equals(ph.get(i).getTitle()))
                                        brw2.borrowBookPH(ph.get(i));
                                    }
                                break;
                        case 2: System.out.println("Input Book Name: ");
                                String borrowID = sc.nextLine();
                                for(int i = 0; i < dg.size(); i++){
                                    if(borrowID.equals(dg.get(i).getTitle()))
                                        brw2.downloadBookDG(dg.get(i));
                                    }
                                break;
                        case 3: System.out.println("Input Equipment Name: ");
                                String borrowIE = sc.nextLine();
                                for(int i = 0; i < eqp.size(); i++){
                                    if(borrowIE.equals(eqp.get(i).getName()))
                                        brw2.borrowEQ(eqp.get(i));
                                }
                                break;
                    }
                    break;
    case 11423970: System.out.println("1. Physical 2. Digital 3. Equipment: ");
                    int choice3 = sc.nextInt();
                    switch(choice3){
                        case 1: System.out.println("Input Book Name: ");
                                String borrowIP = sc.nextLine();
                                for(int i = 0; i < ph.size(); i++){
                                    if(borrowIP.equals(ph.get(i).getTitle()))
                                        brw3.borrowBookPH(ph.get(i));
                                }
                                break;
                        case 2: System.out.println("Input Book Name: ");
                                String borrowID = sc.nextLine();
                                for(int i = 0; i < dg.size(); i++){
                                    if(borrowID.equals(dg.get(i).getTitle()))
                                        brw3.downloadBookDG(dg.get(i));
                                }
                                break;
                        case 3: System.out.println("Input Equipment Name: ");
                                String borrowIE = sc.nextLine();
                                for(int i = 0; i < eqp.size(); i++){
                                    if(borrowIE.equals(eqp.get(i).getName()))
                                        brw3.borrowEQ(eqp.get(i));
                                }
                                break;
                    }
                    break;
    case 11092001: System.out.println("1. Physical 2. Digital 3. Equipment: ");
                    int choice4 = sc.nextInt();
                    switch(choice4){
                        case 1: System.out.println("Input Book Name: ");
                                String borrowIP = sc.nextLine();
                                for(int i = 0; i < ph.size(); i++){
                                    if(borrowIP.equals(ph.get(i).getTitle()))
                                        brw4.borrowBookPH(ph.get(i));
                                }
                                break;
                        case 2: System.out.println("Input Book Name: ");
                                String borrowID = sc.nextLine();
                                for(int i = 0; i < dg.size(); i++){
                                    if(borrowID.equals(dg.get(i).getTitle()))
                                        brw4.downloadBookDG(dg.get(i));
                                }
                                break;
                        case 3: System.out.println("Input Equipment Name: ");
                                String borrowIE = sc.nextLine();
                                for(int i = 0; i < eqp.size(); i++){
                                    if(borrowIE.equals(eqp.get(i).getName()))
                                        brw4.borrowEQ(eqp.get(i));
                                }
                                break;
                    }
                    break;
    case 10911550: System.out.println("1. Physical 2. Digital 3. Equipment: ");
                    int choice5 = sc.nextInt();
                    switch(choice5){
                        case 1: System.out.println("Input Book Name: ");
                                String borrowIP = sc.nextLine();
                                for(int i = 0; i < ph.size(); i++){
                                    if(borrowIP.equals(ph.get(i).getTitle()))
                                        brw5.borrowBookPH(ph.get(i));
                                }
                                break;
                        case 2: System.out.println("Input Book Name: ");
                                String borrowID = sc.nextLine();
                                for(int i = 0; i < dg.size(); i++){
                                    if(borrowID.equals(dg.get(i).getTitle()))
                                        brw5.downloadBookDG(dg.get(i));
                                }
                                break;
                        case 3: System.out.println("Input Equipment Name: ");
                                String borrowIE = sc.nextLine();
                                for(int i = 0; i < eqp.size(); i++){
                                    if(borrowIE.equals(eqp.get(i).getName()))
                                        brw5.borrowEQ(eqp.get(i));
                                }
                                break;
                    }
                    break;
    }
```

Borrower Class:

```
private Physical borrowedP;
private Digital borrowedD;
private Equipment borrowedE;

public void borrowBookPH(Physical borrow){

    this.borrowedP = borrow;
    this.borrowedP.borrowPH(this);

public void downloadBookDG(Digital borrow){

    this.borrowedD = borrow;
    this.borrowedD.borrowDG(this);
    this.borrowedD.countDownload();

}

public void borrowEQ(Equipment borrow){

    this.borrowedE = borrow;
    this.borrowedE.borrowEQ(this);

}
```

Physical Class:

```
    public void borrowPH(Borrower borrower){

    this.isAvailable = false;
    this.borrower = borrower;

}

public void returnPH(){

    this.isAvailable = true;
    this.borrower = null;

}
```

Digital Class:

```
    public void countDownload(){

    this.count += 1;

}

public void showDownload(){

    System.out.println(this.count);
}

public void borrowDG(Borrower borrower){

    this.status = false;
    this.borrower = borrower;
    countDownload();

}
```

Equipment Class:

```
    public void borrowEQ(Borrower borrower){

    this.isAvailable = false;
    this.borrower = borrower;

}
```

Huhu. please help. this 'I can't type anything' is frustrating.

Comment: 1) use a `switch` instead that an `if else` chain. 2) Debug your code and check the line where exception occurs.

Comment: I've noticed that after posting it here, and already changed to switch case. Thank you for pointing that out. Also, the error occurs on borrowBookPH(borrowI) on driver, and also the method borrowbookPH() on Borrower class.

Answer (score 0):

As for the errors, your code seems to lack some try{}catche(){}s and testings(is Physical borrowed, or can I give it to someone?). Also your code is missing the inicialization part, that may also be problematic.

For the error in method, try tracing it, or maybe post e.printStackTrace() with respective code.

And borrow or download should not be a problem, you have them in separate classes and differently named, so what exactly do you mean by "I don't know if the book is really being borrowed or downloaded"

Comment: We haven't tackled try catch or even printstacktrace in class. so basic java would be nice, by books is really being borrowed or download, i meant that. does the download count work, or the isAvailable status change to false from true?